# How could I convert this sentence into a question?

Tags: grammar

"What I  did was cheating."

Is 'Was what I did cheating? Right?

Comment: *"Is what I did considered cheating?"*

Comment: 'Was what i did cheating?' is fine, if you capitalize "I".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are various 'correct' answers, and these could well be supplied on ELL.

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. Nobody in real-life communicaton ever needs to convert an affirmative sentence into a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We can create a question by switching places of the helping verb and the subject. In this case you can switch 'was', which is a helping verb, and 'What I did', which is the subject. Well done.